# What am I missing in Django production deployment?

Tags: django, deployment, wsgi, production

I have the following codes for deploying a Django 1.9 project named `deploy_project` on a CentOS 7 server.

**wsgi.py**

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "deploy_project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

The above was generated by default.

**httpd.conf**

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/deploy_project/deploy_project/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/deploy_project

<Directory /var/www/deploy_project/deploy_project>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

My project directory is in `/var/www/deploy_project`. Inside that I have an app called `Deploy`, the project settings folder called the same as the project name `deploy_project` and the `manage.py` file. I also have a `db.sqlite3` file as I am not using MySQL, but my app just runs a view which shows **Hello World**. I am not using the database.

When I visit the server IP from browser, I receive a 404 Not Found page with the message `The requested URL / was not found on this server.`.

**tree output of project folder**

```
├── db.sqlite3
├── deploy
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templates
│   │   ├── 404.html
│   │   └── deploy
│   │       └── hello.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── deploy_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
└── manage.py
```

**project urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    url(r'^', include('deploy.urls')),
]
```

**app urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.Hello, name='hello'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def Hello(request):
    return render(request, "deploy/hello.html", {})
```

**hello.html**

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: Read [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid That is how I configured the httpd.conf file. What else do I need? If you could kindly point out link to the documentation.

Comment: I added a link to the documentation in my comment. There are multiple supported configuration; but as you are on Apache, the easiest one to get started with would be the [mod_wsgi configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) which you can find here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: In your link you can see the topic `Basic Configuration`, which I have done in my project, you can see the code in my question. The second topic is `Virtualenv`, which I am not using as I have installed Django, Apache and mod_wsgi in the system. The next topic discussed `mod_wsgi daemon`, I am not using that also as I only have one project to run. The next two topic discusses serving static and media files. I only have one view. I just need to know the basics of deployment. I think I have followed all the instructions in that page.

Comment: Please post the output of `tree` on your `/var/www/deploy_project` directory, and the contents of your main `urls.py`.

Comment: Plz check the question again. Updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106125/discussion-between-minigunnr-and-burhan-khalid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being the dumb developer that I am, I didn't restart apache service, so my settings didn't take effect.

For CentOS 7 my command was:

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

That solved my problem. Thanks for your time @BurhanKhalid.